# Android: How to send listview data from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

Hi in my project iam using a actionbar with three tabs(fragments)
from one of the fragment edittext  iam calling a activty via Intent.
In this activity iam doing search and displaying the results in listview.
now when i click the listitem ,the selected list data should come and dit
in the edit text of the fragment.  Below is my code

**From Fragment:**

```
fromtextview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Intent newintent = new Intent(getActivity(), AutoSearchActivity.class);
             startActivity(newintent);
             getActivity().overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );

        }
    });
```

**In activity**

```
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View view, int position,
                    long arg3) {

                // what should be done here??

            }   
        }); 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the android docs at "[Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)", in particular the section "Deliver a Message to a Fragment".

Basically you will need to send the data in a bundle to the Fragment which you can then extract once the Fragment has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Bundle. Here's an example:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in your Fragment, retrieve the data

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
```

or you can also used shared preferences and Sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting a new activity for search, you can start a new fragment from the same activity, switch the view and listview click switch the view back to the first fragment. You will be able to communicate with fragments using the FragmentManager

Comment: Sry,dont have code handy, but these links should help.
The basic idea being that the fragments should communicate with each other through the host activity.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments_activitycommunication

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html